# How to remove a pattern's line and N lines after it?

Tags: macos, sed, yaml

I'm writing a shell script which edits a docker-compose.yml file (running on MacOS).

I'm trying to delete a block which looks like so and is located at the end of the file:

```
  microservice-itai-ms:
    image: ms-itai-ms:master
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
      NPM_TOKEN: 'SECRET'
    ports:
      - "3022:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "redis-cluster"
```

I'm running the following command in order to remove this block:

```
sed -i.bak '/.*itai-ms.*/,+9d' docker-compose.yml
```

9 is the number of lines including the pattern's line.

When I run the above command, I get the following error:

```
echo docker-compose.yml | sed -e '/.*itai-ms.*/,+9d'
sed: 1: "/.*itai-ms.*/,+9d
": expected context address
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pattern,+n` is a GNU extension, are you sure your sed is GNU sed?

Comment: See: [sed use: expected context address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26124650/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "itai-ms" really doesn't appear before the block, and the block really is at the end of the file, you can do this:

```
sed -i.bak '/itai-ms/,$d' docker-compose.yml
```

**EDIT:**

Roughly translated, the command is *"from `/itai-ms/` to `$`* [that is, from the first line containing "itai-ms" to the last line of the file] *execute `d`* [that is, delete the line]"

And if you want to pass "itai-ms" as a variable (call it `X`), try this:

```
"/$X/,\$d"
```

Note the double quotes and the escaped `$`.

Comment: Also, if itai-ms is a variable, how shall I write it? thanks

Comment: This might work, too: `sed -i.bak -e '/itai-ms/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d}' docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @Cyrus: I thought of that, (and it does work,) but `,$d` is shorter.

Comment: @Cyrus: ...But on second thought, your solution fits the *title* of the question better.